# iPhone X - UITableView not displaying all separator lines

Tags: ios

- I created a entirely new Single View project in Xcode 9.3
- I changed `viewDidLoad` in `ViewController` as follows:
- I am missing some separator lines in the tableView shown below on iPhone X / iOS 11.3 simulator.
- This issue does not exist with other iOS versions like iOS 10.x

What do I need to do to get all separator lines?

```
    (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 300, 500) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
      [self.view addSubview:tv];
      tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      tv.separatorColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This only occur in simulator not in device. to verify this in simulator, Enable `Show Device Bezels` from `Window tab` and zoom your `simulator` as much as possible. you will see every separator line.

Comment: as @Kuldeep said this is a simulator issue. Device will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator is scaled. Because of that, it isn't pixel perfect and the tableView lines will sometimes not be shown. This is why it's always best to do the final test on a real device when you can.